# How to modify\convert illegal characters on dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, enums, sdk

I'm trying to make a simple mobile app with dart. I have an enom menu which is

```
enum FD {
  maanantai,
  lauantai,
  sunnuntai,
  päivä,
  juhlapäivä,
}
```

When i use fin alphabet to list days i got an error like:

```
Illegal character '228'.
```

Another question is my main page is also having trouble when i try to use Dan letters. I googled and searched across the web but didnt get ride of that. So is there any way to use illegal characters in a enum?

Comment: Dart identifiers (e.g. variable names, method names, class names, enum constants) [must contain only ASCII characters](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/271#issuecomment-474296489).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Javascript, Dart identifiers must be ASCII only.
That means you can't label enums, variables, classes etc with "special" characters like `ä`.

You can however use them in strings. So `String s = "juhlapäivä"` will work just fine.